# Add marker onclick google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, external

I have this functions with Google Maps API to add markers.

Is it possible to show a marker info on a href link click?

My markers are loaded dynamicly..

This is a bit of my code so far but it doesnt work.

```
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                    function addMarker(lat, lon, naam, straat, postcode, plaats, telefoon, afstand)
                    {
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
                            map: map,
                            icon: "afbeeldingen/pincard/wheel-icon.png",
                            title: naam
                        });

                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                            var contentString = '<div>'+
                            '<b style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">' + naam + '</b><br/>'+
                            'Afstand (hemelsbreed): ' + afstand + ' km<br/>' +
                            straat + '<br/>' +
                            postcode + ' ' + plaats + '<br/>';
                            if(telefoon != "")
                            {
                                contentString = contentString + 'Telefoonnr: ' + telefoon;
                            }
                            contentString = contentString + '</div>';
                            infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        });


                    }

                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
                </script>
```

This is the href I use:

```
<a href="javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');">Click</a>
```

Any help would be welcome:)

Comment: Have you try to declare marker as a global ?
The problem of this is that "marker" will be the latest created...

Answer (score 0):

I got the sidebar thing working properly now. :)

This is my final code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        var geocoder;
                        var map;
                        var side_bar_html = ""; 
                        var gmarkers = []; 
                        var infobox;
                        function initialize() {

  var blueOceanStyles = [
    {
      featureType: "all",
      elementType: "all",
      stylers: [
        { saturation: -100 } // <-- THIS
      ]
    }
];

                            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                            var myOptions = {
                                zoom: <?php
                                if(is_array($postcodevelden) && count($postcodevelden) > 0 && !empty($_POST['address']))
                                {
                                    switch($radius)
                                    {
                                        case "5":
                                            echo "12";
                                            break;
                                        case "10":
                                            echo "11";
                                            break;
                                        case "15":
                                        case "20":
                                            echo "10";
                                            break;
                                        case "30":
                                        case "40":
                                            echo "9";
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo "7";
                                }
                                ?>,
                                center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php if(is_array($postcodevelden) && count($postcodevelden) > 0) { echo $lat.", ".$lon; } else { echo "52.2008737173322, 5.25146484375"; } ?>),             
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                            }
                            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
                            map.setOptions({styles: blueOceanStyles});

<?php
        if(is_array($adressen) AND count($adressen) > 0) 
        {
            foreach($adressen as $adres)
            {
                $afstand = round((6371 * acos(sin(deg2rad($lat)) * sin(deg2rad($adres->locatie_lat)) + cos(deg2rad($lat)) * cos(deg2rad($adres->locatie_lat)) * cos(deg2rad($adres->locatie_lon) - (deg2rad($lon))))), 2);
?>
                            addMarker(<?php echo $adres->locatie_lat.", ".$adres->locatie_lon.", '".$adres->locatie_naam."', '".$adres->locatie_straat."', '".$adres->locatie_postcode."', '".$adres->locatie_plaats."', '".$adres->locatie_telefoon."', '".$afstand."'"; ?>);
<?php
            }
        }
?>
document.getElementById("marker_list").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
                        }
                        function myclick(i) {
  map.setCenter(gmarkers[i].getPosition());
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}
                            infowindow = new InfoBox({
                             content: document.getElementById("infobox"),
                             disableAutoPan: false,
                             maxWidth: 150,
                             pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0),
                             zIndex: null,
                             boxStyle: {
                                background: "url('http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/tipbox.gif') no-repeat",
                                opacity: 0.95,
                                width: "280px"
                            },
                            closeBoxMargin: "12px 4px 2px 2px",
                            closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
                            infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
                        });

                        function addMarker(lat, lon, naam, straat, postcode, plaats, telefoon, afstand)
                        {
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
                                map: map,
                                icon: "afbeeldingen/pincard/wheel-icon.png",
                                title: naam
                            });

                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                                var contentString = '<div id="infobox">'+
                                '<b style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f6ee34; color:#ee2a24;">' + naam + '</b><br/>'+
                                'Afstand (hemelsbreed): ' + afstand + ' km<br/>' +
                                straat + '<br/>' +
                                postcode + ' ' + plaats + '<br/>';
                                if(telefoon != "")
                                {
                                    contentString = contentString + 'Telefoonnr: ' + telefoon;
                                }
                                contentString = contentString + '</div>';
                                infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            });
                                gmarkers.push(marker);

    side_bar_html += '<tr>'+ '<td onclick="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')"><a>' + naam + '<br/>' + straat + '<br/>' + postcode + ' ' + plaats + '<br/>' + 'Afstand ' + afstand + ' km' +'</td>' +'<\/a></tr><br>';

                        }

                        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
                    </script>
```

I get a complete list of all zipcodes in the range that the user entered. Now I can't figure out how I can sort the output in the sidebar, but that's another question.

Comment: Since you have a solution to the original question, you should ask a new question about the new problem. I've edited this answer to focus on being an answer. [Please use Answers exclusively to answer the question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/92107). If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. x